Integrating Red Hat Identity Management Server (IPA) i.e Cockpit with corporate Windows LDAP server
I am trying to integrate Red Hat IPA server with corporate LDAP server so that only those users can log in to Red Hat Identity Management UI (IPA) which exist in the corporate LDAP.
Currently, everyone is using a root account to log in to Red Hat Identity Management UI and console.
I searched through the Red Hat documentation but got confused when it said use authconfig ui or ipa-client-install, and they said use ipa-client-install utility, but they have not explained very clearly how to do so. Anyone knows the steps how to do this integration?

When you say "corporate LDAP server" do you mean Active Directory? If so please say so because there are specific interfaces that can use this

Is this what you're trying to achieve? - https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/about-active-directory#about-active-directory

yes, it is Active Directory when I said corporate LDAP server, my intention is to get the users logins details from AD, authenticated  and then users can login to redhat identity IPA server or redhat identity web page. I am  trying to pull the user details from AD

@ChrisDavies, the given link talks about replication of the users in both linux identity and AD, I am after more how to point redhat identity managemnt to LDAP for authentication. I am not looking to double up users in both AD and redhat Idm system

I am trying to point Redhat Cockpit web UI to LDAP so that users can authenticate against AD to login to Cockpit web page

Oh ok. In that case I'd suggest you raise a call with RedHat and ask them
